# Firestore saves large floats as integers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save large float values (like 1.7976931348623157e+308) in a Firestore database and they are all being cast to integers. The same integer,  9223372036854776000, actually.

The value is added via an expressjs cloud function

```
app.post("/addFloat", (request, response) => {
  console.log("/api/addFloat", request.body.myfloat) //logs correctly as a float in firebase console
  admin.firestore().collection(`/test/${request.params.docId}/floats`)
    .add({
      bigFloat: request.body.myfloat,
      test: 1.234 // correctly stored as a float
    }).then(docRef => {
      return docRef.get()
    }).then(docSnapshot => {
      response.status(200).json(docSnapshot.data()); //bigFloat is now 9223372036854776000 in both response and db
    }).catch( error => {
      response.status(9).json({error:error});
    })
})
```

Curiously, logging the snapshot itself to the Firebase console reveals:

```
...
_fieldsProto: 
{ bitFloat: 
   { integerValue: '9223372036854775807',
     valueType: 'integerValue' } },
...
```

So at some point it Firebase decided to use an integer instead of a float.

I understand I could split the float into two 32bit uints, but since Firestore docs [says it supports 64 bit floating point numbers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) I'd rather not. Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What do you think the actual type of `request.body.myfloat` is?  Could it be a string that just looks like a float?  If so, you might need to manually convert it to a floating point number so that the Firestore SDK knows what best to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Doug. I took a look and the float is definitely arriving as a number. Logging typeof response.body.float gives "number" and I even tried passing it through parseFloat(), same result: 9223372036854776000

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm starting to suspect this might be an issue with the Firestore SDK itself. From my cloud function, I called .add({ test: Math.random()*Number.MAX_VALUE }) and the result was the same as my issue. And for what it's worth it's the same if I add a record with a dummy float 1.234 and update it to the large float.

Comment: Well, if you have a solid repro for a bug, please file it: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/